# How to call static resource image in another static resource css file?

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

How to call static resource image in another static resource css file?.i save one image in static resource as a name flowerimage.then that flower image calling from css as a url($Resource.flowerimage, 'flowerimage.png').those css are in saved in another static resource file name as "cssstyles".then i am calling that css file in page 

but i am not getting image in page.how to call resource image in static resource css file.can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

One solution (assuming you can re-organize the files) is to put both the images and CSS in a zip file that you then add as a static resource.

The image reference can then be relative e.g.:

```
url("../images/Sortbybutton.png")
```

so avoiding the need for the `$Resource` reference (that can only be processed in a Visualforce page).

See e.g. [How to refer my static resource zip file ( CSS & Img) in VF Page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92248/how-to-refer-my-static-resource-zip-file-css-img-in-vf-page/) for an example.

You can add the CSS to the page using e.g.:

```
<link href="{!URLFor($Resource.myzip, 'css/mycss.css')}" rel="stylesheet" />
```